# How to bind popup in the centre of a layer react leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a `<Map>` component with `<Geojson>` component with in it. I want to bind a popup in onEachFeature method.

I have successfully done `layer.bindpopup()`; but don't know how to bind it to the centre of the geoJson layer.

adding a `<Popup ref="popup">` in `<Map>` and doing `this.refs.popup.getLeafletElement()` throws an error, so I am not being able to use `popup.setLatlang()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply trying to have a popup show upon clicking a geojson feature?  If so you can follow the [basic example of react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/docs/Getting%20started.md).

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

const position = [51.505, -0.09];
const map = (
  <Map center={position} zoom={13}>
    <TileLayer
      url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    />
    <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>
        <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  </Map>
);

render(map, document.getElementById('map-container'));
```